# URL vs URI (Why always convert URL(any data) to URI)

Tags: android, parsing, url, android-intent, uri

Why do we always convert URL string to URI or any data when we pass the data to intent object?

I know that parameter type of Intent is URI type but what is so special about URI?

What is the concept behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL is used to identify a specific resource and how to access it - in all completeness

**URI:** `mysql://localhost@databasename:password`

The URL shows you where you can find the database on the internet and which protocol you should use.

**URL:** `mysql://localhost`

Comment: I am not asking for the difference between URL and URI
suppose i am using contacts using intent
     Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:+651234567"));

or for getting geo location
Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:37.827500,-122.481670"));

now why i am parsing these info(ph. no. & geo-location) to uri